# Autolayout Constraint Issues on UINavigationbar and Uibuttons

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, navigationbar

I have Screen with Navigationbar ,title ,textfields and buttons.I want to design the page for universal application. But my Screen fixed in ipad but not in iphone. how to fix that?

Comment: Can you specifically tell what problems you are facing with iPhone?

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar Title of the navigation and textfields not showing correctly

Comment: Add a screenshot of the incorrect part. And you might want to also show the constraints set for the textfields.

Comment: @zcui93 screen shot added

Comment: What's the method you used for adding title? And any special constraints set for the labels and textfields?

Comment: Show us the constraints. It appears you are not setting the trailing space constraints correctly for the textfields at least.

Comment: @NSNoob  Constraints added

Comment: @GaneshKamath can u help this

Answer (score 0):

As far as navigation bar is concerned you can set leading constraint to margin for back button, horizontal centre constraint for the margin and trailing constraint for DONE button. And for label and textfield you can see in image attached below. You can set your margins accordingly.

[image: constraints]